# android : html list view not working in the string.xml file

Tags: android, textview

I have to insert a list (not the android list view but simple html list) in a fragment. The layout file "about.xml" page has only one textview which is being clustered dynamically , taking data from the string.xml file .
The declaration in the string.xml is like this :

```
<string name="AboutThisApp"><![CDATA[

<div>
    <p>here is the list of functions: </p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li> Sportsmanship</li>
    <li> Participation</li>
    <li> Safety/Risk Minimization</li>
    <li> Sound Traditions of the Sport</li>
    <li> Support for USA Footvall\'s Mission</li>
    <li> Balance Between Offense and Defence</li>
</ul>

]]></string>
```

This data is being accesses in a textview present in the layout folder which is as follows (file is "about.xml"):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAbout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            customText:textcustomFont="fonts/montserrat-r.ttf" />
```

The object accessing the data in the java file is as follows :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.usafootball.rulesapp.R;
import com.usafootball.rulesapp.customfont.TextViewPlus;

public class AboutThisAppFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about,
                container, false);
        TextViewPlus textViewPlus = (TextViewPlus) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAboutUSAF);
        textViewPlus.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.AboutThisApp)));

        return mView;
    }

}
```

To make it more clear the data is being displayed but it appears in a form of a paragraph NOT LIST . Any suggestions how to do this...

Comment: <div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Sportsmanship</div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Participation</div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Safety/Risk Minimization</div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Sound Traditions of the Sport</div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Support for USA Footvall\'s Mission</div>
 <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8226 Balance Between Offense and Defence</div>
</div>
this is a very hard coding technique and i won't recommend to use this way. Instead use the webview technique to use the list view.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `<ul>`, `<li>` tags are not supported by `TextView`, that is why its not working. See the list of supported tags here: [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. TextView not support all html tag.
2. Use WebView rather than TextView.

**layoutname.xml**
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

**string.xml**
<string name="AboutThisApp">&lt;div>
    &lt;p>here is the list of functions: &lt;/p>
&lt;/div>

&lt;ul>
    &lt;li> Sportsmanship&lt;/li>
    &lt;li> Participation&lt;/li>
    &lt;li> Safety/Risk Minimization&lt;/li>
    &lt;li> Sound Traditions of the Sport&lt;/li>
    &lt;li> Support for USA Footvall\'s Mission&lt;/li>
    &lt;li> Balance Between Offense and Defence&lt;/li>
    &lt;/ul>

</string>

**activity**
 private WebView webview;
 // write below code in onCreate()
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.loadData(getString(R.string.AboutThisApp),"text/html","utf-8");
```